# How can I get value by using c++ 11 multithreading

Tags: multithreading, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

int foo(int n){
    int doubleN = n * 2;
    return doubleN;
}


int main(){
    int n = 2;
    thread t(foo,n);
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

In terms of above code, can I get doubleN's value in main function and how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get result of task executed by thread, you can use `async` function:

```
int foo(int n){
    int doubleN = n * 2;
    return doubleN;
}


int main(){
    int n = 2;
    future<int> result = async(std::launch::async, foo,n);
    cout << result.get() << endl; //4
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::promise` and `std::future`, cppreference `std::promise` documentation has an example to demonstrate using `promise<int>` to transmit a result between threads ([link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise)).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future>

using namespace std;

int foo(int n, std::promise<int> doubleN_promise){
    int doubleN = n * 2;
    doubleN_promise.set_value(doubleN);
    return doubleN;
}

int main(){
    int n = 2;
    std::promise<int> doubleN_promise;
    std::future<int> doubleN_future = doubleN_promise.get_future();
    thread t(foo, n, std::move(doubleN_promise));
    doubleN_future.wait();  // wait for doubleN
    std::cout << "doubleN=" << doubleN_future.get() << '\n';
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```